# How to load javascript without affecting your baseURL in webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to load url(Text from assets) in `WebView` then I set textSize & margin to that `WebView`, using javascript.

But When I do that I don't see my "Text from assets" and see only javascript-function as a string!

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            int size = ((miSizeLevel + 1) * 5);
            int margin = ((miMarginLevel + 1) * 5);
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontSize = '" + size + "px';");
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.margin = '" + 10 + "px " + 10 + "px " + 10 + "px " + 10 + "px';");
        }
    });
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/input.html");
    return rootView;
}
```

Here is my webview screenshot :

[image: webview]

Where I am going wrong?
Please suggest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is little change in writing `javascript` function.

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ document.body.style.fontSize = '"+size+"'})();");
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ document.body.style.margin = '"+margin+"'})();");
```

Enjoy coding :)

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to execute javascript method

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:functionName()");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have these settings?

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Yes I have these lines.

Comment: Could you add please the full code for the webview related class and the HTML file?

Comment: Thank you for help, But I found solution, Thanks again :)